# How to maintain multiple documents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-access, document-management

I have a list with different positions that form a schedule of prices. That list is over 12 pages long. Some of these prices are adjusted yearly, while others are not. So far, the adjustments were made manually. 
However, as the document grows, the effort to update the file manually increases also. 
I am looking for a way on how to easily maintain several documents.

I thought about creating an Excel file where every position with its price is listed. Excel allows to easily adjust the prices. However, linking them to Word and creating a meaningful document is also cumbersome. Inserting new lines in Excel, moving the files in another directory etc. destroys the whole document.
There has to be a better solution.

I also thought about using Access, creating entries for all price positions and somehow link them to word. Unfortunately I am not sure if that even works.

Maybe it is somehow possible to define the document as follows:
Select doc_description from masterfile where....
Select price from masterfile..etc...

What I want is a Master Document (Access, Excel, etc..) where every subdocument obtains the prices from the Master Document.

Comment: For auto update you need VBA for User Form which is rather easier in ACCESS has so many built it facilities. Or if you don't like coding then Excel itself has built in Form, can be used for Data Management also !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Excel filters or pivot table should do this is you configure columns of data correctly.

Can include "flag" columns that contain "Y" for each type of subdocument if that helps

DLC